# plot function to limit in R

Tags: r, math

Say I have a simple mathematical function `n1=m1*n1` and I want to plot this function as n1 approaches infinity. Is there a quick way to do that?

```
m1=0.1
```

initial `n1=0.1`

Or do I have to used deSolve and setup a differential equation? There must be a quick way to do this.

Comment: This looks like a discrete map (i.e. `n1(t+1)=m1*n1(t)`) rather than a differential equation.  Do you mean `d(n1)/dt = m1*n1` ? R doesn't have symbolic computation capabilities (e.g. taking limits) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the next value in this equation depends on the last value you would set up something like this:

```
m1 <- 0.1
x <- seq(0.1, 1000, 0.1)
y <- c(0.1, rep(NA, length(x)-1))

for(i in 2:length(x)){
  y[i] <- y[i-1] * m1
}

plot(y~x, type = "l" )
```

Comment: yes it's a derivative, your examples do not work. The value at the initial state is used to compute the value at t+1. Why would you assign values of y if you don't know what they will be.

Comment: Following the initial state of 0.1 then next value is 0.01, the next is 0.001, and so on and so forth. The above code states that the value of `y` at time `t` is dependent on the value of `y` at `t-1`, which is exactly the same as saying the the value following the initial state (`t=2`) is dependent on the initial state (`t=1`). This is just done through a for loop.

Comment: I don't understand why you initialize y with a  seq function, then.

Comment: We are writing over the values so it does not really matter what is initially in them (aside from the first value). I edited the answer so that only the first value in the vector holds anything (0.1), and the rest of the vector is just NA values.